# Verb without "be" in sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

Are the below sentences are incomplete?

> a) Police arrested the person who killed his brother.

It is unable to understand without context that killing referring to past or present.

That is, would this be better?

> Police arrested the person who (**has/had**) killed his brother.

---

Likewise:

> b) Accused interrogated for 2 hours for the murder charges against him.

Here also it is unable to understand that interrogation referring to past or present. Should it be:

> Accused (**is/was**) interrogated for 2 hours for the murder charges against him.

Answer (score 1):

In both of your sentences, it's the simple past that is used.

Both sentences also read as if they are written in [*headlinese*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese), where syntactic components are removed, traditionally because of a lack of space.

The first sentence is complete. *Killed* is the simple past tense.

---

The second sentence is also complete. *Interrogated* is the simple past tense.

Even with the addition of *is* before *interrogated*, it would still be referring to a past event:

> Accused is interrogated for 2 hours.

Because a time period has been specified, and it's not phrased as a future event, we know that the period of time has already passed.

---

In contrast, however, this would be describing a present event:

> Accused is being interrogated.

It's the specific use of *is being* that allows the simple-past form of *interrogated* to be treated as a present action.

Note that it would be unidiomatic to add a time period at the end of this sentence. Doing so wouldn't make sense. Instead, the sentence would need to be rewritten: *Accused is interrogated for 2 hours—and still being interrogated.*

---

To reinforce what I said at the start, this is all written in *headlinese*. Standard English would add in several missing syntactical components that would make the meaning clearer.

Comment: The first one is not headlinese.

Answer (score 1):

These are two separate cases. In the first case, "Police arrested the person who killed his brother." would be fine. It is implied that the person "had killed" his brother because it occurred after the police "arrested" which is past tense. Likewise, it would be incorrect to say "Police arrested the person who *has* killed his brother."

In the second case, the is/was is necessary for a complete sentence because the sentence is passive in this case. The interrogation is being done by someone else to the accused. However, in certain cases "Accused interrogated for 2 hours for the murder charges against him" is acceptable (the only obvious case I can come up with is a newspaper headline which doesn't need a complete sentence). In these rare cases, the implication generally is that the accused *was* interrogated.

Answer (score 1):

> It is [not possible] to understand without context that killing referring to past or present.

"Killed" is past tense, so it refers to the past. The only ambiguity there could be is whether it happened before or after the arrest. The default interpretation is before, but this could made more clear by adding "had". If it happened after, one could express that by saying "The police arrest the person who would later go on to kill his brother".

> Accused interrogated for 2 hours for the murder charges against him.

As Jason Bassford says, this appears to be headlinese. Normally, it would be "the accused". "Interrogated" is clearly past tense, but if the accused is the recipient, rather than performer, of the interrogation, it should be "was interrogated". Also, "regarding the murder charges" or "in connection to the murder charges" would be more natural than "for the murder charges"